# Building extensions to AWS Lambda with Continuous Delivery

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda, travis-ci

I have a GitHub repository containing a AWS Lambda function. I am currently using Travis CI to build, test and then deploy this function to Lambda if all the tests succeed using

```
deploy:
    provider: lambda
    (other settings here)
```

My function has the following dependencies specified in its `requirements.txt`

```
Algorithmia
numpy
networkx
opencv-python
```

I have set the build script for Travis CI to build in the working directory using the below command so as to have the dependencies get properly copied over to my AWS Lambda function.

`pip install --target=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR -r requirements.txt`

The problem is that while the build in Travis CI succeeds and everything is deployed to the Lambda function successfully, testing my Lambda function results in the following error:

```
Unable to import module 'mymodule': 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

My best guess as to why this is happening is that numpy is being built in the Ubuntu distribution of linux that Travis CI uses but the Amazon Linux that it is running on when executing as a Lambda function isn't able to run it properly. There are numerous forum posts and blog posts such as [this](https://markn.ca/2015/10/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/) one detailing that python modules that need to build C/C++ extensions must be built on a EC2 instance.

My question is: This is a real hassle to have to add another complication to the CD pipeline and have to mess around with EC2 instances. Has Amazon come up with some better way to do this (because there really should be a better way to do this) or is there some way to have everything compiled properly in Travis CI or another CI solution?

Also, I suppose it's possible that I've mis-identified the problem and that there is some other reason why importing numpy is failing. If anyone has suggestions on how to resolve this that would be great!

---

**EDIT:** As suggested by @jordanm it looks like it may be possible to load a docker container with the amazonlinux image when running TravisCI and then perform my build and test inside that container. Unfortunately, while that certainly is easier than using EC2 - I don't think I can use the normal lambda deploy tools in TravisCI - I'll have to write my own deploy script using the aws cli which is a bit of a pain. Any other ideas - or ways to make this smoother? Ideally I would be specify what docker image my builds run on in TravisCI as their default build environment is already using docker...but they don't seem to support that functionality yet: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7726

Comment: You could do your build inside of a amazon linux docker container.

Comment: That sounds interesting - would it be possible to do that with TravisCI?

Comment: Yes, https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/

Comment: @jordanm see my edit on the original post.

Comment: Looks like you are not actually doing the build within docker, just pulling the image

Comment: Yeah I think that is what I'm doing :) In order to do everything from within the docker image I think I have to write a custom deploy script for lambda and a custom test script..which is a bit of a pain. I wish there was a way to run the entire build on top of a docker container and you can specify the image to pull...maybe there is some other CI provider that does that?

Comment: @abagshaw Gitlab CI offers that. But you could do it in Travis, it may be a bit complicated but it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a bit of tinkering I think I've found something that works. I thought I'd post it here in case others have the same problem.

I decided to use [Wercker](http://www.wercker.com/) as they have quite a generous free tier and allow you to customize the docker image for your builds.

Turns out there is a docker image that has been created to replicate the exact environments that Lambda functions are executed on! See: https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda When running your builds in this docker container, extensions will be built properly so they can execute successfully on Lambda.

In case anyone does want to use Wercker here's the `wercker.yml` I used and it may be helpful as a template:

```
box: lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
build:
  steps:
    - script:
        name: Install Dependencies
        code: |
          pip install --target=$WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR -r requirements.txt
          pip install pytest
    - script:
        name: Test code
        code: pytest
    - script:
        name: Cleaning up
        code: find $WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR \( -name \*.pyc -o -name \*.pyo -o -name __pycache__ \) -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
    - script:
        name: Create ZIP
        code: |
          cd $WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR
          zip -r $WERCKER_ROOT/lambda_deploy.zip . -x *.git*

deploy:
  box: golang:latest
  steps:
    - arjen/lambda:
        access_key: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
        secret_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
        function_name: yourFunction
        region: us-west-1
        filepath: $WERCKER_ROOT/lambda_deploy.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I appreciate you may not want to add further complications to your project, you could potentially use a Python-focused Lambda management tool for setting up your builds and deployments, say something like [Gordon](https://github.com/jorgebastida/gordon). You could also just use this tool to do your deployment from inside the Amazon Linux Docker container running within Travis.

If you wish to change CI providers, [CodeShip](https://codeship.com) allows you to build with any Docker container of your choice, and then [deploy to Lambda](https://blog.codeship.com/integrating-aws-lambda-with-codeship/).

[Wercker](https://wercker.com) also runs full Docker-based builds and has many user-submitted deploy "steps", some of which [support deployment to Lambda](https://app.wercker.com/explore/steps/search/lambda).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - I decided to go with Wercker and after a bit of tinkering I came up with a working solution. I posted it here as others may find it helpful.